# dhclient.conf modifications do not change resolv.conf

Tags: kali-linux, dns, networkmanager, dhcp

When I modify my /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf with prepended nameservers, after a network manager restart, the generated resolv.conf file does not contains these servers. I'm working on Kali Linux.

Here is my dhclient.conf

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting NetworkManager does not necessarily mean re-running the DHCP request process; if the current DHCP lease is still valid and the network interface is already configured, NetworkManager may just keep using it as-is. You'll want to explicitly disconnect & reconnect the specific network connection NetworkManager is using.